# Ambigous operator in gcc

Tags: c++, c++17

I made a function template for printing some of the stl containers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <template <typename, typename> class C, typename T, typename A>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C<T, A>& container)
{ 
    for (auto& elem : container) 
    { 
        os << elem << " "; 
    } 

    return os; 
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v { "One", "Two", "Three" };

    std::cout << v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and works as expected on MSVC, Clang and ICC, but when compiling with GCC(trunk) it gives an ambigous `operator<<` error for the line `os << elem << " "`. And even this error appears only when compiling with the flag `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++2a`.

The error seems reasonable, for `std::string`, since compiler detects an existing function template that for global `operator<<` that accepts an output stream and a `basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>`, with the `Allocator` type being defaulted to `std::allocator`.

My question would be why does it compile and work with the other 3 compilers, from my understanding ,Clang at least, uses the same standard library implementation on linux as gcc, so it has the same function template for the `operator<<`

The error reported is

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')
```

And the two candidates

```
note: candidate: 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const C<T, A>&) [with C = std::__cxx11::basic_string; T = char; A = std::char_traits<char>; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]'

note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
```

Compiler arguments for GCC, Clang and ICC

```
-std=c++2a -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror
```

An for MSVC

```
/std:c++latest /O2 /W3
```

Mandatory godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/R_aSKR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The error seems reasonable, for `std::string`, since compiler detects an existing function template that for global `operator<<` that accepts an output stream and a `basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>`, with the `Allocator` type being defaulted to `std::allocator`.

This ability to match a parameter like `C<T, A>` to a type like `basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator=std::allocator<CharT>>` is new in C++17, it comes from [P0522](https://wg21.link/p0522). Prior to that paper, your operator would not be considered as a candidate.

However, clang intentionally chooses not to implement this feature by default. From [their status](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html):

> Despite being the resolution to a Defect Report, this feature is disabled by default in all language versions, and can be enabled explicitly with the flag `-frelaxed-template-template-args` in Clang 4 onwards. The change to the standard lacks a corresponding change for template partial ordering, resulting in ambiguity errors for reasonable and previously-valid code. This issue is expected to be rectified soon.

You can see that when you add that flag, your code becomes ambiguous on clang as well. Your example is the kind of reasonable and previously-valid code that clang is protecting against here. A similar kind of example I've seen:

```
template <class T> struct some_trait;

template <template <class> class C, class A>
struct some_trait<C<A>> { /* ... */ };

template <template <class> class C, class A, class B>
struct some_trait<C<A, B>> { /* ... */ };
```

`some_trait<vector<int>>` used to be okay (using the binary version), but now becomes ambiguous (between the unary and the binary version).

MSVC might make the same choice, but I do not know. The correct answer per the standard is that the call is ambiguous.